# why is python ignoring the elif and else statement and only doing the task based on the if statement no matter what the outcome of random.choice()

Tags: python

it always prints You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side. It even does this if it is not true

```
usinp = input ("Which scenario would you like to do first 1,2, or 3?")
if usinp == "1":
    print ("You are playing the Packers in OT of the 2014 NFC championship team.")
    firplay = input ("It's your ball on the Seattle 13. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? HB gut, Hail Mary, or WR screen pass?")
    if firplay == "HB gut":
        import random
        _1 = "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
        _2 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _3 = "Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"

        PossibleOutcomes = [_1,_2,_3]

        def example():
            print (random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)) 
            if "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" in PossibleOutcomes:
                print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

            elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" in PossibleOutcomes:
                print("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Strong HB toss, Hail Mary?")

            else:
                print("You would be a horrible head coach your team would never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")



        example()
```

Comment: Your if statement is simply checking that one of the possible outcomes is in the list of possible outcomes. Of course it is, so it will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually store your choice. And your test is checking if the first string is in the `list` of options, not whether it was chosen; since the first string is always in the `list` of options, the first block always fires, excluding the other blocks from being tested. For the minimalist fix:

```
    def example():
        mychoice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
        print(mychoice) 
        if "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == mychoice:
            print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

        elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" == mychoice:
            print("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Strong HB toss, Hail Mary?")

        else:
            print("You would be a horrible head coach your team would never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not saving the outcome of the random choice correctly, That is why only your if statement is getting executed. You want to check if the outcome of the random choice is matching with your if or elif or else statement. So this is the logical issue here. :)

Which can be fixed simply by doing,

```
            choice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
            if "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == choice :
                print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

            elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" == choice:
                print("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Strong HB toss, Hail Mary?")

            else:
                print("You would be a horrible head coach your team would never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")
```

Oh by the way welcome to stack over flow. :) And a bonus tip: no matter how it looks, if and else statements do not have any issue ever, it's always small bit of your logic. Printing the variable values is the simplest method to check what is going on from debug point of view. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code line by line :D

```
# this takes the input for which scenario you want. looking good :)
usinp = input("Which scenario would you like to do first 1,2, or 3?")

# this block of code runs when the user input is 1
if usinp == "1":

    # ooo, cool storyline
    print("You are playing the Packers in OT of the 2014 NFC championship team.")

    # gets another user input
    firplay = input("It's your ball on the Seattle 13. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? HB gut, Hail Mary, or WR screen pass?")

    # this runs if the input was HB gut
    if firplay == "HB gut":

        # gets the function defined inside random
        import random

        # these are all the choices availiable
        _1 = "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
        _2 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _3 = "Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"

        # this is the list of possible outcomes. looking good so far
        possibleOutcomes = [_1,_2,_3]

        # a cool little function :D
        def example():

            # this prints out a random choice. hmm, how do you know which choice it is?
            print(random.choice(possibleOutcomes)) 

            # this code checks if that line is in the possible outcomes. it always is :|
            if "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" in possibleOutcomes:
                print("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

            # that flaw on the if statement above means this code will never run...
            elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" in possibleOutcomes:
                print("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Strong HB toss, Hail Mary?")

            else:
                print("You would be a horrible head coach your team would never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")



        # this runs the flawed function
        example()
```

How do you fix this? Just get a variable to remember which random choice was made.

Replace the part after `def example():` with this:

```
choice = random.choice(possibleOutcomes)

print(choice)

if "Yay you scored a 93 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == choice:
    print("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")
...
```

TL;DR: Replace `print(random.choice(possibleOutcomes))` with `choice = random.choice(possibleOutcomes)` `print(choice)`, and then replace the `in possibleOutcomes` with `== choice`. Have a great day :D